# PBS batch job submission

Tags: pbs

I have 100 scripts with .bash extension and I want to submit all of them in one shot in pbs script. I used 
qsub *.bash
But it is not working. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 1):

One way it to simply loop over the files:

```
for i in `ls -1 *.bash` ; do qsub $i ; done
```